# How to create CASE WHEN "contains"?

Tags: regex, case, looker-studio, re2

Is there a possibility to search for names in `Source`?

```
CASE
  WHEN Source="facebook_instagram" OR Source="facebook.com" OR Source="m.facebook.com" OR Source="instagram.com" OR Source="instagram" OR Source="l.facebook.com" OR Source="lm.facebook.com" OR Source="facebook" OR Source="de-de.facebook.com" THEN "Social"
  ELSE "Sonstige"
END
```

Is there a way to select all `facebook` sources, without listing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved using the [`REGEXP_MATCH`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7064476) function within a [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statement; the RegEx below looks for `facebook` or  (`|`) `instagram` regardless of what the string starts with (`^`), what comes before the text (`.*`), after the text (`.*`) or what it ends with (`$`):

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Source, "^.*(facebook|instagram).*$") THEN "Social"
  ELSE "Sonstige"
END
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/10ae3331-a3d7-47f3-996a-b7e6fe036e2e) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly reduce the amount of code by using REGEXP_MATCH

For example

```
CASE
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Source, '.*facebook.*') OR REGEXP_MATCH(Source, '.*instagram.*') THEN 'Social'
ELSE 'Sonstige'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option to get rid of some of the duplication is to use [in](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724#in). For your code that would result in something like:

```
CASE 
WHEN Source IN("facebook_instagram", "facebook.com", "m.facebook.com", "instagram.com", "instagram", "l.facebook.com", "lm.facebook.com", "facebook", "de-de.facebook.com") Then "Social"
ELSE "Sonstige" 
END
```